# Ubuntu stuck on loading screen

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, ubuntu-20.04

I dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 after using it for a while I try to boot it but the screen just stays at this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUA0Z.jpg

I have an AMD Cpu and a Nvidia Gpu and I have recently upgraded do 16GB RAM i hope there is a way to fix this

Comment: Have you tried restoring the original RAM configuration to see if that caused the issue??

Comment: @DrMoishePippik , It worked with the new ram once but afterwards it didn't so i don't think it's because of the ram

Comment: It seems like it's not finding a boot drive/partition (assuming motherboard POST is OK). You could try booting from an Ubuntu Live/CD/USB and see if the HDD and partitions are still active.

Comment: @user3169 the partitions are active but, every time I turn my PC only the windows 10 drive is detected i have to restart the PC for the Ubuntu drive to be bootable

Comment: An other thing is the windows 10 has the boot thing on the linux drive, both drives are GPT but when I don't reset the pc it just says it isn't a proper boot device so if you'd know how to fix it that would help linux worked just fine with it though

Comment: I'm not clear yet. Can you confirm the following? 1. Each OS is on a separate physical drive. 2. Boot order is Ubuntu first. 3. In Ubuntu Grub menu, selecting Ubuntu loads Ubuntu OK. 4. In Ubuntu Grub menu, selecting Windows won't boot and you get result shown in your question. 5. If 1. is correct, with only Windows drive connected, Windows loads OK.

Comment: @user3169 1 yes. 2. Yes. 3. No it won't 4. Selecting Ubuntu will make this result, windows boots just fine 5. Bootloader is on the Ubuntu drive so no it won't

Comment: Are you using GRUB2? Highlight the Ubuntu entry; press `e` to edit; from the `linux` line remove `quiet` and `splash` parameters; press `Ctrl+x` to boot. This should show you some messages. When it gets stuck, take a picture and post it in the question body ([edit] the question).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't know what grub2 is, and it's a black screen but,  before I removed the parameters it ended on a black screen with a cursor

Comment: It seems like your Ubuntu installation is broken somehow. At the menu you select OS to boot from, Ubuntu should be at the top. Below that is something like Advanced Options. Select it and you should see a menu of recently installed Linux kernals. Select one (not the top one) and see if that works.

Comment: Otherwise, I think you need to install Ubuntu again. Of course, backup any important files first. Before installing, disconnect the Windows drive so it won't be affected. Then confirm Ubuntu by itself works OK. Then reconnect Windows drive. Also, I would add the details confirmed above to your question. As written, it can't be answered because of no detailed information on the problem.

Comment: @user3169 I have reinstalled Ubuntu and it boots and gets to a black screen with a mouse i have not yet even logged in

Comment: Can you log in via a tty? (Ctrl+Alt+F2).

Comment: @Maciorowski nope doesn't work still a black screen

Comment: Macriorowski @user3169 i have reinstalled Ubuntu again and it worked for the first boot then after an another restart it booted into the desktop but the background are blue now, desktop icons lose their visuals and iam unable to open terminal or anything else